# can we send data or files via wifi from a Raspberry PI using a QT graphical interface to another pc under Windows?

Tags: wifi, data-transfer, qt

so my Raspberry card is connected to a screen by HDMI, I want to develop an interface using the QT platform under linux to give the order to my Rpi card to send data or files and even to receive according to the need of the user, these data then will be sent/received via wifi towards another PC which run under WINDOWS so that this last one can display them.
if someone can give me just the idea and if it is feasible, I would be grateful.
thank you in advance for your help
Kail

Comment: Yes you can. First, your RPi must be connected to the same network as your Windows PC (RPi as WAP ?). Your QT app. must implement for example a server (using UDP or TCP) capable of hosting your files and receiving them. An example using [qtcpserver](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html) or [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html). You can also install an existing web server (nginx, apache...) and communicate locally with your QT app to save you from coding a server.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on your purpose if you want a more specific answer or help but I think you'll have better luck on a forum dedicated to your specific needs instead of a forum dedicated to the RPI card.